# Simple/Advanced search

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to implement a simple and advanced search which lets me just type in a search for a default parameter but also has an advanced search box.

For example in the search box i search for "from" and "to" with a date range and it fills out the simple search with "from:xx/xx/xxxx to:xx/xx/xxxx" and will convert that for a get request.

I think what I need is a regex to split `keyword:...`, `keyword:...` and end of string up.

I other words, what is the regex to split "criteria1:blah blah criteria2:foo criteria3:bar"

or another solution would be a jquery plugin that does this.

Comment: Did you have a specific question?

Comment: Arent RegExps limited to a maximum of 10 variables?

Comment: @Amberlamps: Where did you read that?

Comment: @Felix: http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/regexp.htm#dollar_1_9 You should be able to read this I guess ;)

Comment: Some implementations (maybe, even in js) have limit of max 10 back-references, but with `global` flag this is not a problem. Also, modern js engines surely allow max 99 such variables.

Comment: @Amberlamps: Ah I see. But you will still be able to use more capture groups to extract the relevant information I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to use positive look-ahead:

```
"criteria1:blah blah criteria2:foo criteria3:bar"
    .match(/([\w\d]+:[\w\d\s]+?)(?= [\w\d]+:|$)/g)
// returns ["criteria1:blah blah", "criteria2:foo", "criteria3:bar"]
```

You'll need to change what characters allowed as criteria name and criteria value.

Comment: would this work if criteria1 = blah blah blah blah? or any number or params?

Comment: Of course. Space is allowed as criteria value (see `\s` in second brackets). If you want, you may think about different use/test cases and update your answer with them.